# My code works, in the sense that it runs what I want it to do, but once the user guess the number correctly, the terminal ends and does not loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)


while True:
    pick = input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. ")
    pick = int(pick)
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")

    while True:
        if pick > number:
            print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
            break       
        elif pick < number:
            print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
            break
```

## the code runs the way i'd like it to, but it stops after one correct guess, and i'd like the loop to restart once the user guesses the number correctly

Comment: i miss wrote the code on the question, i have indented it and still doesnt work

Comment: Why not all your code is inside **one** `while True:`? Why the `if ==` check is inside one `while True:` and both the `if >` and the `if <` checks are separated on the other `while True:`? I think that this is your mistake.

Comment: because it won't loop an incorrect answer

Comment: because it wo**n't** loop an **in**correct answer is the same to say because it will loop a correct answer. Double negations cancel each other. Is my reasoning wrong? Now it is even worse after your edit. The `if ==` check is done only **once**.

Comment: i'm not sure, but trust me i've tried. if i include the < and > inside the first while loop then you can only guess one incorrect answer and then the terminal will end

Comment: But you choose the random number *outside* the loop.  If you loop again with a correct answer then it would just expect the same number again.

Comment: What happens when you guess the number correctly on the first go? You still enter the second "while" loop but you get stuck there since pick=number. You're stuck in the inner loop infinitely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply adding Continue fixes it. I used the number 5 to test the code.

```
import random

number = 5

while True:
    pick = input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. ")
    pick = int(pick)
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")
        continue

    while True:
        if pick > number:
            print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
            break
        elif pick < number:
            print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
            break
```

I further simplified your code below

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)

while True:
    pick = input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. "+ str(number))
    pick = int(pick)
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")
    if pick > number:
        print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
    elif pick < number:
        print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
```

Comment: Continue does fix it, but the logic is overly complicated. The second while loop isn't needed since any time is enters it either immediately exits or gets stuck infinitely. The continue just prevents it from getting stuck

Comment: YES IT WORKED AWESOME THANK YOU!

Comment: @Kabdmenrs, If you're satisfied with it then good but as nijave has said, there are simpler logics to do what you want. It one of the means to an end.

Comment: Since you're not changing the number, if I guess it correctly one time, then I'll always guess it correctly.

Comment: please see the updated code. It has less lines and works better.

Comment: your simplified code doesnt work :) it changes the number each time and thats the problem thats why i used a second while loop. your first change worked like a charm.

Comment: Oh, ok, i guess I didn't read it properly. If you put  `number = random.randint(1, 100)` outside of the loop it'll do exactly as you want

Answer (score 2):

Use one while and one break :

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)

while True:
    pick = int(input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. "))
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")
        break # correct guess, break
    elif pick > number:
        print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
    else: # one possibility left, so no need for another elif
        print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
```

A test-case :

```
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 80
That was too high of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 60
That was too high of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 40
That was too low of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 50
That was too low of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 55
That was too high of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 53
That was too low of a guess. Try again.
Choose a number between 1 and 100. 54
You are correct, great job!
```

If you don't want it to stop after a correct guess, remove the break, and guess again :

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)

while True:
    pick = int(input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. "))
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")
        number = random.randint(1,100) # guess again
    elif pick > number:
        print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
    else: # one possibility left, so no need for another elif
        print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
```

Comment: no this works yes i know but when you guess correctly it does not run again

Comment: If you want to run it again after a correct guess, then how do you intend to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the random number generation inside the loop as well, otherwise it will just test for the same number over and over:

```
import random

while True:
    number = random.randint(1,100)

    pick = input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. ")
    pick = int(pick)
    if pick == number:
        print("You are correct, great job! ")

    while pick != number:
        if pick > number:
            print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
            break
        elif pick < number:
            print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
            break
```

Note that I replaced your `while True` infinite loop with a test for correctness.

Edit:

However, you can simplify it further:

```
import random

pick = 0
while True:
    number = random.randint(1,100)

    while pick != number:
        pick = input("Choose a number between 1 and 100. ")
        pick = int(pick)
        if pick == number:
            print("You are correct, great job! ")
            break
        elif pick > number:
            print("That was too high of a guess. Try again. ")
        else:
            print("That was too low of a guess. Try again. ")
```

Comment: There is still no need for the second while loop if you're immediately breaking every time. The program would function exactly the same by removing the second while (and un-indenting the code, obviously)

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I was trying to keep as much of the original code as possible.